# StringFormat shows error in Designer, but not after compiling

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, string-formatting

I have a C#/WPF Programm with MVVM.

Both `Kalkulation.Artikel.PartWeight` and `Kalkulation.Artikel.SprueWeight` are decimals. 
The **Format** of both shall have one optional decimal place and a thousand seperator.

I've implemented this like in the screenshot below.
[image: Error in StringFormat]

*For each `StringFormat` I get* **three** *errors:*

```
Error   XLS0112 Expected ''.    Kalkulation MainWindow.xaml 113 
Error   XLS0414 The type '' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built. Kalkulation    MainWindow.xaml 113 
Error   XLS0112 Expected '
```

The picture shows the signs, that could not be displayed by Stackoverflow.
[image]

**When i compile, i have no Error at all, everything works as expected!**
The Errormessages pop up again, when i change something i the XAML Code.

I have turned the Sync between Display an Textbox off to enter decimals with ease. 
`FrameworkCompatibilityPreferences.KeepTextBoxDisplaySynchronizedWithTextProperty = false;`

What can i do to change this? Can i at least "filter" the error messages?

Comment: Did you try wrapping your `StringFormat` value in single quotes? Somethink like `StringFormat='{}{0:#,##0.#}'`.

Comment: Yea, this was all i needed ... thanks

Answer (score 10):

If you already have single quotes and still get `XLS0112 XAML` errors, the delimiter `{}` in front of the formatting requests `{0:C0}` may be missing.

Be careful with any reformatting that removes all leading text which does not require the delimiter!

Good:

`stringformat='Currency {0:C0}' // Proper string formatting`

`stringformat='{}{0:C0}' // Proper string formatting`

Bad:

`stringformat='{0:C0}' // Functions but raises "XLS0112 XAML"`

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution...
I had to put **single quotes** around it beacause it contained commas.
The commas are interpreted as separators, but the compiler kept it together.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when stringformatting a DateTime, like this:

```
Text="{Binding MyDateTime, StringFormat='yyyy-MM-dd&#x0a;HH:mm:ss'}"
```

where `&#x0a;` is a NewLine character.

The solution for me was to escape the NewLine character with an extra backslash like this:

```
Text="{Binding MyDateTime, StringFormat='yyyy-MM-dd\&#x0a;HH:mm:ss'}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by manually deleting obj/bin folder and rebuilding the solution.

Please see [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/126372/updating-vs2017-caused-some-property-in-xaml-error-with-error-code-xls0431) for a similar issue in Xamarin.

Comment: Sorry mate, didn't work, but it's good to know for the future!